# How to select rows from a table based on duplicated values in a column Snowflake

Tags: filter, group-by, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, having

I have a table A that looks similar to:

| ID | PET | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | DOG | US |
| 72 | DOG | CA |
| 15 | CAT | CA |
| 36 | CAT | US |
| 37 | CAT | SG |
| 12 | SNAKE | IN |
| 20 | PIG | US |
| 14 | PIG | RS |
| 33 | HORSE | IQ |

(has about a few hundred rows)

I would like to retain the rows that have a duplicated "PET" value, so the result looks like:

```
|ID|PET |COUNTRY
|--| --- |---|
|45| DOG |US|
|72 |DOG|CA|
|15 |CAT |CA|
|36 |CAT|US|
|37 |CAT|SG|
|20|PIG|US|
|14|PIG|RS|
```

How can I remove the rows that do not have duplicated PET values? Would it be something like

```
SELECT ID, PET, COUNTRY, COUNT(*)
FROM A 
GROUP BY PET, COUNTRY, ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

I am not sure how to group the values by PET and pick out the groups only containing one row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply doing:

```
WITH 
RES AS (SELECT PET, COUNT(*) FROM A GROUP BY PET HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT ID, PET, COUNTRY FROM A WHERE PET IN (SELECT PET FROM RES);
```

This would give you all rows with pets present in more than one row.

Comment: But I would like to remove the groups with one row which is why I was trying ```HAVING COUNT(*)>1```

Comment: Ok, I got it now, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way is to use `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PET) > 1;
```